# Instant time range

Tags: java

How do I get the starting and ending hour of a given Instant.
Eg: If my Instant is 2016-05-18T09:25:17.554Z then I need string like 
2016-05-18T09:00:00.000Z-2016-05-18T10:00:00.000Z

i.e I need the time window where my instant lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Java 8 time API it can be done like this:

```
final Instant instant = Instant.parse("2016-05-18T09:25:17.554Z");
final Instant startInstant = instant.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS);
final Instant endInstant = startInstant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
System.out.println(instant + ", " + startInstant + ", " + endInstant);
```

This prints `2016-05-18T09:25:17.554Z, 2016-05-18T09:00:00Z, 2016-05-18T10:00:00Z`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Apache commons-lang, you can use DateUtils to get the highest and lowest dates:

```
Date date = Date.from(instant);;
Date high = DateUtils.ceiling(date, Calendar.HOUR);//to get higher
Date low = DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.HOUR); //to get lower
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the magic number 86400000

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
Instant instantStart = Instant.ofEpochMilli((instant.toEpochMilli() / 86400000) * 86400000);
Instant instantEnd = Instant.ofEpochMilli((instant.toEpochMilli() / 86400000) * 86400000 + 86400000);
System.out.println(instant);
System.out.println(instantStart);
System.out.println(instantEnd);
```

**Output :**

```
2016-05-18T09:47:03.782Z
2016-05-18T00:00:00Z
2016-05-19T00:00:00Z
```